# Google cloud VM instance CPU usage very high, and growing month by month

Tags: google-cloud-console

I have configured a VM Instance in Google Cloud with nodered, mqtt, grafana and influxdb, and wireguard tunnel.

It is used only by me, for my home domotic system.

Only few devices.

CPU is growing month by month.

I have already read about that you can't compare TOP command with CPU utilization in google cloud monitoring service because of: *"The CPU usage shown in Google Cloud Console is not that of the instance, but the CPU usage of the container managing the instance. This container is in charge of providing the virtualization services to the instance and collecting all the metrics used for load balancing, auto-scaling, cloud monitoring, etc. As such, high numbers of I/O or network operations will cause the CPU utilization shown in Cloud Console to spike."*

But how could I get managed what is the real reason ?

With TOP I can't see anything, as the CPU is under 5%, but VM instance is over 80%. (one month ago, about 50%)

Thanks a lot.

NOTE: For example, last 30 days:

[CPU USAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgEMP.png)

Comment: Do you periodically reboot your instance?  I found that I have to do that to maintain VM health.  I chose once a week.